# Line break in SSRS is not working properly

Tags: reporting-services, line-breaks, ssrs-2008-r2

I am getting improper affect of my `SSRS expression` for line break. I've done quite alot of research about the syntax, I have tried using `Fields!......+ VbCrLf  + Fields!...,` or
`Fields!...+System.Environment.NewLine+Fields!..."` OR tried with double Carriage return `( ...+VbCrLf +VbCrLf +...)`

In my case, either one of these works in first two lines only. And I can't get the effect in my 3rd and 4th lines. I also make the `textbox` can-grow properties to `True`. But still not okay. Someone please kindly help me resolve this issue. Thank you...

Comment: Can you show the report output

Comment: If your placeholder is in html enabled mode then  try "<br />"  for a newline

Comment: @bmsqldev Hi I've used </br> in html embedded mode, but no changes. ![IMG]http://i67.tinypic.com/2e5sagw.jpg[/IMG]  http://tinypic.com/r/2e5sagw/9 Sorry for thepicturequality. The report layout result incorrectly. This is the expression i am using. ="<u>"+ Fields!P_remark_Cname.Value +"</u>"
+ System.Environment.NewLine +
 "<u>"+Fields!P_remark_CPost.Value +"</u>"
+ System.Environment.NewLine +
 "<u>"+Fields!P_remark.Value+ "</u>"
+"</br>"
 +System.Environment.NewLine+System.Environment.NewLine+"<u>"+Fields!Remark_rank.Value+"</u>"

Comment: Are you just trying to join a number of fields together in one text box, without performing any calculation on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include multiple fields in a single textbox by simply adding more placeholders to a single text box.

Fore example you can add you original expression for `Fields!P_remark_Cname.Value`.  Then enter as many carriage returns as required, then right click the text box and select "Create Placeholder".  Set the value of the window that pops up to `=Fields!P_remark_CPost.Value` and then OK out of the windows.

You can repeat this process for as many variables as you like, resulting in a design that looks like this

[image]

Note you can also format each of these expressions *individually*, hence some appearing bold, or underlined as required.

Hopefully this will be helpful.  Please let me know if you require further assistance with this.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I've tried using multiple placeholders. Yes, it is more convenient because I can  format the text easily. But the thing is, I have to use the smallest height as much as possible for the textbox because I have no data in some of the subsequent rows and I dun want to show so much gap between one row and another. And I have to use can-grow property True as well. (note.The textbox is inside the tablix)